# Sorting of names in an array of structs

Tags: c, arrays, struct

So I have a long list of bikers that I need to sort into an array of struct so it goes

Race, First Name, Last Name, Age, Team, Nationality, placement and running time.

So far I have managed to do that, but when I come to a guy that has two first names (In this problem Mads Wurst) it messes my entire array up, and no matter what I try it doesn't seem to fix it.

The list of names look like this:

ParisRoubaix               "Mickael DELAGE"                               32  FDJ   FRA      43      5:50:48

ParisRoubaix               "Iljo KEISSE"                                  35  QST   BEL      44      5:50:48

ParisRoubaix               "Matthieu LADAGNOUS"                           33  FDJ   FRA      45      5:50:48

ParisRoubaix               "Mads Wurtz SCHMIDT"                           23  KAT   DEN      46      5:50:48

ParisRoubaix               "Dylan GROENEWEGEN"                            24  TLJ   NED      47      5:50:48

ParisRoubaix               "Reto HOLLENSTEIN"                             32  KAT   SUI      48      5:50:48

And my code looks like this:

```
int printAllRiders(void){
  char full_data_array[RACE_DATA_SIZE];

  race_results *each_race = malloc(sizeof(race_results)*RACE_DATA_SIZE);

  FILE *inputp;
  inputp = fopen("cykelloeb-2017.txt", "r");

  int i = 0;

  if(inputp != NULL)
  {
   while(i<50/*(temp_var = fgetc(inputp)) !=EOF*/)
   {
  fscanf(inputp, " %s \"%[-A-z] %[ ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'  ]\" %[0-9] %[A-Z] %[A-Z] %s %s", 
    each_race[i].race, 
    each_race[i].name_first, 
    each_race[i].name_last, 
    each_race[i].age, 
    each_race[i].team, 
    each_race[i].nationality, 
    each_race[i].placement, 
    each_race[i].finishing_time);

  printf("Race: %s\n, first name: %s\n, last name: %s\n, age: %s\n, team: %s\n, nationality: %s\n, placement: %s\n, time: %s\n", 
    each_race[i].race, 
    each_race[i].name_first, 
    each_race[i].name_last, 
    each_race[i].age, 
    each_race[i].team, 
    each_race[i].nationality, 
    each_race[i].placement, 
    each_race[i].finishing_time);
  i++;
}
 } else {
printf("ERROR: Input file could not be opened");
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 }

fclose(inputp);
full_data_array[i] = '\0';
  }
```

Comment: But what is the issue? Please elaborate more.

Comment: Btw, I hope you are not using actual data and names in your example, you should have anonymized samples to work on.

Comment: Can you put some example of the problem your dealing with ? It's a bit hard to understand what you're meaning by "it messes my entire array up"